# unable to update Status of product from csv

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, csv, status

When I change the status field of product from enable to disable or vice versa via updating through csv using data flow profile, it is not updating value of status, simply leaves status of a product blank.
While manually I am able to update products as well as products status is inserted properly of new products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing status from  DataFlow Profile use  'Enabled' or 'Disabled'  in 'status' field.
For Import/Export 1 or 2 should be indicated in 'status' field.