# Magento 1.7. - Update status attribute via Dataflow Profile

Tags: product, magento-1.7, import, csv, profiler

We are trying to UPDATE the status attribute via Dataflow Profiles and CSV file.
The CSV is processed correctly (no error messages in the popup showing the process), so the settings in the Dataflow Profile are OK. We can use both of these:

[image]
and 
[image]

The CSV just holds the SKU and status values and looks like

[image]

But no matter which values we are using for ‚status‘ in the CSV – ‚Enabled‘ or ‚Disabled‘ – ‚enabled‘ or ‚disabled‘ (no captal letters) and even ‚1‘ or ‚2‘ (or ‚0‘ instead of 2) as it would be used in the normal import like answered under a similar question here 
[unable to update Status of product from csv](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151780/unable-to-update-status-of-product-from-csv)
the status doesn’t get updated. The CSV is UTF-8 encoded.

Sorry for asking such a basic question here, but I have googled for hours to find a reason/solution to our problem, but haven’t found any hint or indication as to why the status attribute is not updated via Dataflow Profile.

The system is on Magento 1.7.0.2.

Comment: instead on Enabled use '1' and try, it should work

Comment: Thanks, we already used '1' instead of 'Enabled' but this didn't work either.

Comment: rather than dataflow profile, have you tried with the simple magento import ?